# Why is there an gap between the articles?

Tags: html, css

I created an section with three articles, im wondering why there is an margin/padding betwenn the articles:

[image]

My html:

```
<section id="home">

 <article>
<h1>Übersicht</h1>
 </article>
 <article>
<h1>Leute</h1>
 </article>
 <article>
<h1>Links</h1>
 </article>

 </section>
```

And my css:

```
section { width: 87%;
    margin: 0px auto;
     }

article {
    width:33%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color:blue; 
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace inline-block with block and use `float:left` Please see this fiddle

[`JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/tYy7v/)

Answer (score 1):

There is *whitespace* between the `display:inlin-block` elements. Just remove them, example:

```
<section id="home">
    <article><h1>Übersicht</h1></article><!--
    --><article><h1>Leute</h1></article><!--
    --><article><h1>Links</h1></article>
</section>
```

Or:

```
<section id="home">
    <article><h1>Übersicht</h1></article><article><h1>Leute</h1></article><article><h1>Links</h1></article>
</section>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XRYzE/1/)

Or adding `font-size:0;` to the *parent* container, [example](http://jsfiddle.net/XRYzE/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Any two `inline` or `inline-block` elements are rendered with a white space between them, even if you have several spaces/new lines separating them in the markup.

For example, these 3 divs, will all render `hello world`:

```
<div>hello world</div>

<div>hello
world</div>

<div>

   hello


       world
</div>
```

This happens because the text nodes are `inline`.

In your case, you need to make sure, the opening `<article>` is immediately after the previous closing `</article>`:

```
<section id="home">
 <article>
<h1>Übersicht</h1>
 </article><article>
<h1>Leute</h1>
 </article><article>
<h1>Links</h1>
 </article>

 </section>
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9wmPt/)

Taking the above example, here you don't want `hello world`, you want `helloworld`, so just remove any spaces between these 2 words in the markup.

Answer (score 1):

The spaces is added by your browser automaticly.

A widly accepted fix for this is by adding `font-size:0` to the parent container and then a reasonable font size to the child elements

In your case you would do this:

```
section {
    font-size: 0;     //Must be zero
}

article {
    font-size: 10px;  //can be anything you want

    width:33%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color:blue; 
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Display inline block is exactly what it is. An inline element with block properties. So that being said if you have a white space / line break between the elements it will add a gap.

I suggest using display: block and float: left in this case. This method also adds support for older browsers. If you prefer to use inline-block, remove the white space so that the end tag and beginning tag of the elements are directly next to each other.

http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/